# Using WSO2 Identity Server with OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

While trying to use WSO2 Identity Server with  OpenLDAP after following the steps on:
http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/user-core/admin_guide.html#LDAP

I get this message, when trying to authenticate:

```
TID: [0] [WSO2 Identity Server] [2012-07-30 13:30:34,088]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  None active tenant trying to sign in.example.com {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin}
TID: [0] [WSO2 Identity Server] [2012-07-30 13:30:34,088] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  Your account is not active. Please activate your account first. {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin}
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Your account is not active. Please activate your account first.
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin.login(AuthenticationAdmin.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
TID: [] [WSO2 Identity Server] [2012-07-30 13:30:34,100] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient} -  Error occurred while logging in {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Your account is not active. Please activate your account first.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:64)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:85)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
TID: [] [WSO2 Identity Server] [2012-07-30 13:30:34,105] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext} -  error occurred while login {org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext}
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Exception occured
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:87)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:150)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:85)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Your account is not active. Please activate your account first.
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:70)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:142)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Your account is not active. Please activate your account first.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
    at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:64)
    ... 27 more
```

My user-mgt.xml is:

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
                <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>admin@example.com</UserName>
                     <Password>admin</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
            <MaxUserNameListLength>500</MaxUserNameListLength>
            <Property name="url">jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB</Property>
            <Property name="userName">wso2carbon</Property>
            <Property name="password">wso2carbon</Property>
            <Property name="driverName">org.h2.Driver</Property>
            <Property name="maxActive">50</Property>
            <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property>
            <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>
    </Configuration>
    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://192.168.81.128:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin@example.com,ou=users,dc=maxcrc,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=users,dc=maxcrc,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system,dc=maxcrc,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
    <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager"></AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

Can you give any suggestions as to where the error might be?

The only user on my OpenLDAP installation is admin@example.com with password admin

Comment: what is the Identity Server version you are using ? Have you commented out any configuration in the ApacheDSUserStoreManager configuration in the user-mgt.xml

Comment: I'm using 3.2.3, looks like there was some problems with my configuration file, things got mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to connect to the OpenLDAP in read only mode use the LDAPUserStoreManager instead the ApacheDSUserStoreManager. When you do the configurations do not comment out or remove configuration elements, cause that would would cause for NULL POINTER EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: Found the errors on the configuration, but now I'm presented with another error, I have changed the question to better address the problem (since the first one was just things mixed up :S)

Comment: Ah, you had to create a new question for this, because someone else would get the same problem you had in future. But anyways it seems the user account is not activated in OpenLDAP

Comment: How can I verify this? And how could I activate it?